# Есть ли в директории хоть один файл с заданным расширением?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Возникла потребность узнать есть ли в директории (и поддиректориях) хоть один файл с определённым расширением.

На самом деле я уже создал метод для этого, но интуиция подсказывает что он недостаточно оптимален. Собственно вопрос в том, можно ли добиться заданной цели более эффективно?

```
    public bool IsExistAnyAudioFile(string path)
    {
        StringComparison comp = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
        var findFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".opus", comp) || s.EndsWith(".ogg", comp) || s.EndsWith(".tak", comp));

        foreach (string f in findFiles)
        {
            return File.Exists(f);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: А для чего тут цикл for?

Comment: Зачем вообще проверять существование файла второй раз? вы не доверяете результату `Directory.EnumerateFiles`? Просто напишите `return findFiles.Any();`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну может же быть вариант, когда файл был стерт после вызова енумератора но до вызова проверки :)

Comment: @Grundy, ага, а также может быть что файл был удален после `File.Exists`, до того как результатом воспользуется внешний код :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, хм, а можно это как-то предотвратить? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, наверное, можно заблокировать файл. У меня пока ни разу не было такой нужды. Задайте отдельным вопросом ;)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, но ведь чтобы его заблокировать он должен присутствовать, но после проверки присутствия и до блокировки его ж могут удалить :-) пъяблемка :-)

Comment: @Grundy, поэтому надо пытаться блокировать сразу и возвращать признак успеха или провала операции. Т.е. `File.Exists` в любом случае не нужен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно переписать так:

```cs
var findFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                         .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".opus", comp) || s.EndsWith(".ogg", comp) || s.EndsWith(".tak", comp));

return findFiles.Any(File.Exists);
```

Строго говоря, это не будет *оптимальнее*. Под оптимальнее скорее всего, вы имеете в виду *быстрее*. Эта задача решается всегда за линейное время, так что если у вас перебор в цикле по массиву до первого подходящего элемента, это уже оптимально.

Метод `Any` делает то же самое, что и ваш код, но его вызов чуть короче.

С другой стороны, как тут подсказали в комментарии, вызывать `File.Exists` не нужно, поскольку метод `EnumerateFiles` возвращает *существующие* файлы.

А предикат проверки расширений можно вынести в `Any`, так что код можно упростить так:

```cs
public bool IsExistAnyAudioFile(string path)
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    return files.Any(s => s.EndsWith(".opus", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                       || s.EndsWith(".ogg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                       || s.EndsWith(".tak", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

**UPDATE**

Обновил код по комментарию @АндрейNOP. Расширения вынес как приватное статическое поле класса, чтобы инициализировались только одни раз.

```cs
private readonly ICollection<string> extentions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    ".opus",
    ".ogg",
    ".tak"
};


public bool IsExistAnyAudioFile(string path)
{
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                    .Select(Path.GetExtension)
                    .Any(extentions.Contains);
}
```

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, а зачем проверять наличие файла еще раз через `File.Exists`. разве не будет достаточно простого .Where(...).Any() ?

Comment: @morphey83 комбинация where и any вообще бессмысленная, достаточно в any передать необходимый предикат

Comment: @morphey83 Я, честно говоря, эту часть вообще не продумывал, сделал так, как в оригинальном вопросе. Но Вы правы, так что я включил это в ответ.

Comment: Ну и осталось поместить список расширений в HashSet, вычленять расширение файла из пути с помощью `Path.GetExtension` и проверять вхождение с помощью `Contains` :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, done. :)

Comment: а почему в начальной маске не задать расширение?

Comment: @Grundy Не уверен, что `EnumerateFiles` умеет операцию ИЛИ над маской.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, ага, [освежил в памяти](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_), он только `*` и `?` поддерживает, несколько кардинально разных не получится :-)

Comment: Ну теперь красота :)

Comment: На самом деле вариант с IReadOnlyCollection не совсем подходит к данному вопросу, так как он возможен лишь начиная с .net 4.5, а у меня .net 4.0. Впрочем его наверно можно заменить на System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection. Однако Visual Studio подчёркивает System.Collections.Generic.HashSet, утверждая что "Использование универсального типа HashSet<T> требует аргументы типа 1". Что имеется ввиду я не совсем понимаю...

Comment: @Raf-9600, если .NET 4.0, то можно использовать `ICollection` вместо `IReadOnlyCollection`. Исправил ответ.

Comment: @Mark Shevchenko, проблема в другом - Студия HashSet подчёркивает и пишет какую непонятную ошибку. Замена ReadOnlyCollection на ICollection не меняет ситуацию.

Comment: @Raf-9600, попробуйте `HashSet<string>()`. Я код проверил в студии, но, похоже, скопипастил неправильно. Исправил ответ.

Comment: @Mark Shevchenko, благодарю, всё работает. Чуть-чуть офтоп: для получения списка всех аудиофайлов необходимо использовать такой вариант, верно? `var findFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(audioPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => extentions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s)));`

Comment: @Raf-9600, да. `Where` фильтрует файлы по условию, а условие — расширение файла есть в нашем списке.