# Как получить список файлов из папки на c#?

Tags: c#

Проблема в следующем: мне нужно из какой-либо папки получить список файлов. То есть я пробегаю по папке, проверяю каждый файл, и если формат подходит - то записываю файл в список. А как мне пробежаться по папке?

Comment: А что вы самостоятельно сделали, почему не пользуетесь `DirectoryInfo`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Есть ли в директории хоть один файл с заданным расширением?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/940565/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Comment: Ну а как я могу его тут использовать? Мне нужно пробежаться по папке, у меня есть список типа Bitmap, мне надо в этот список записать подходящие файлы. DirectoryInfo пробовал, GetInfo пробовал. GetInfo возвращает список типа FileInfo, а мне нужен Bitmap.

Comment: А какое отношение Bitmap имеет к FileInfo? Получите список файлов например по расширению и работаете с ним. Опишите задачу полностью - ибо описанная задача решается 2-мя строчками

Comment: У меня имеется уже написанная мной программа: я по одной загружаю картинки и могу их перелистывать. Мне нужно, чтобы я мог перелистывать картинки сразу из какой-либо папки. Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно проверить каждый файл этой папки, и если подходит формат, то записать его в список типа Bitmap про который уже говорил. GetInfo возвращает список файлов из папки. Список типа FileInfo. А мне надо записать все файлы .png и .jpg  в список.

Comment: У FileInfo есть свойство Name, оно возвращает имя файла с расширением (например name.jpg). Вы можете разбить имя, проверить тип расширения и если это подходящий файл, то на его основе создать Bitmap (передав ему адрес нужного файла)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно проверять тип файла в директории и если он `jpg` или `png`, то создавать Bitmap (в конструкторе указать путь до нужного файла):

```
 DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo("сюда указать путь до папки");
         List<Bitmap> myList = new List<Bitmap>(); //ваш лист с Bitmap
         foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles()) //проходим по файлам
         {
            //получаем расширение файла и проверяем подходит ли оно нам 
            if (Path.GetExtension(file.FullName) == "jpg" || Path.GetExtension(file.FullName) == "png")
               myList.Add(new Bitmap(file.FullName)); //если расширение подошло, создаём Bitmap
         }
```

UPD. Изменил ответ, добавив Path.GetExtension(). Спасибо **Alexander Petrov**

Comment: Спасибо большое, выручили!

Comment: Имя файла вполне может содержать точки. Поэтому `Name.Split('.')[1]` может вернуть не расширение, а часть имени. Лучше используйте метод [Path.GetExtension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: конструктор `new Bitmap(String)` понимает форматы BMP, GIF, EXIF, JPG (расширения *.jpeg и *.jpg), PNG и TIFF.

Comment: @Alias Я с вами согласен. Просто автор вопроса указал только два формата, я их и написал в примере

Comment: @alladuh я не спорю) просто хотел заметить что формат JPEG в двух расширениях( *.jpeg и *.jpg) и если вы его проверяете сравнением строк...