# Пакетное переименование файлов C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Есть папка в которой находятся несколько файлов с короткими именами. Есть excel или txt файл в котором есть колонка "Старое имя" и "Новое имя", где соответственно указано текущее имя файла, и новое которое должно быть.
Например: Вас -> Васильев Василий Викторович
Задача на С# в том, чтобы заменить все старые имена на новые (подтягивая их из Excel файла соответственно), с учетом вложенных папок. И так-же нужно показать имена которые изменились и не изменились.
Подтягивание с Excel и переименование сделал, вот код:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application ObjWorkExcel = new Excel.Application(); //открыть эксель
            Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook = ObjWorkExcel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Files\Test1.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); //открыть файл
            Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1]; //получить 1 лист
            var lastCell = ObjWorkSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);//1 ячейку
            int lastColumn = (int)lastCell.Column;//!сохраним непосредственно требующееся в дальнейшем
            int lastRow = (int)lastCell.Row;
            string[,] list = new string[lastCell.Column, lastCell.Row]; // массив значений с листа равен по размеру листу
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)lastCell.Column; i++) //по всем колонкам
                for (int j = 0; j < (int)lastCell.Row; j++) // по всем строкам
                    list[i, j] = ObjWorkSheet.Cells[j + 1, i + 1].Text.ToString();//считываем текст в строку
            ObjWorkBook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); //закрыть не сохраняя
            ObjWorkExcel.Quit(); // выйти из экселя
            GC.Collect(); // убрать за собой -- в том числе не используемые явно объекты !

                for (int j = 0; j < lastRow; j++) // по всем строкам 
                {
                    System.IO.File.Move(list[0, j] + ".jpg", list[1, j] + ".jpg");
                    Console.WriteLine("Файл " + list[0, j] + " был переименован в " + list[1, j]);

                    // Console.Write(list[i, j] + " ");  //выводим строку 
                }


                Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
}
```

Но оно переименовывает только файлы одного типа, и только в папке с exe-шником проекта, а нужно чтобы могло любого типа и в любой папке.
Пробовал еще так, но тогда переименовывает случайно 1 файл, нету сравнения и поиска:

```
 var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Photo");
            foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
                for (int j = 0; j < lastRow; j++) // по всем строкам 
            {
                    string newFileName = $@"{(list[1, j])}{file.Extension}";
                    string newFileFullPath = Path.Combine(file.DirectoryName, newFileName);
                    File.Move(file.FullName, newFileFullPath);
                    //System.IO.File.Move(list[0, j] + ".jpg", list[1, j] + ".jpg");
                    Console.WriteLine("Файл " + list[0, j] + " был переименован в " + list[1, j]);
```

Вот так работает правильно, но только с jpg файлами и только в папке с exe-файлом.

```
System.IO.File.Move(list[0, j] + ".jpg", list[1, j] + ".jpg");
```

Если убрать +".jpg" то будет ошибка "файл не найден".
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы можно было выбрать любую папку и расширение файла?

UPD.
Решил вопрос. Сделал так:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите путь к файлам которые нужно переименовать:");
            Console.Write("> ");
            var files = Console.ReadLine();
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(files);
            foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < lastRow; j++) { 
                    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name) != list[0, j])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Такого файла нет " + list[0, j]);

                    }
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < lastRow; j++) // по всем строкам 
                {
                    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name) == (list[0, j]))
                    { 
                    string newFileName = $@"{(list[1, j])}{file.Extension}";
                    string newFileFullPath = Path.Combine(file.DirectoryName, newFileName);
                    File.Move(file.FullName, newFileFullPath);
                    //System.IO.File.Move(list[0, j] + ".jpg", list[1, j] + ".jpg");
                    Console.WriteLine("Файл " + list[0, j] + " был переименован в " + list[1, j]);
                    break;

                    }

                    // Console.Write(list[i, j] + " ");  //выводим строку 
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Осталась 1 проблема, как сделать вывод списка файлов, которые не были найдены в папке?
Пробую так (возвращаю список имен из папки, и если они не равны списку из Excel, значит их нет):

```
for (int j = 0; j < lastRow; j++) { 
                    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name) != list[0, j])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Такого файла нет " + list[0, j]);

                    }
                }
```

Но оно выводит не только файлы которых нет в папке, а и те файлы которые есть, просто не сразу были найдены, а на n-нный круг цикла.
А нужно чтобы реально только те которых нет. Но как это сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971128)

Comment: Спасибо, уже сделал)
Осталась 1 проблема, как сделать вывод списка файлов, которые не были найдены в папке?
Пробую так (возвращаю список имен из папки, и если они не равны списку из Excel, значит их нет):

`for (int j = 0; j < lastRow; j++) { 
                    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name) != list[0, j])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Такого файла нет " + list[0, j]);
                        
                    }
                }`

Comment: Но оно выводит не только файлы которых нет в папке, а и те файлы которые есть, просто не сразу были найдены, а на n-нный круг цикла.
А нужно чтобы реально только те которых нет. Но как это сделать?

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, внесите туда актуальную информацию

Comment: Хорошо, уже внёс.